# How to sort by multiple columns in C1FlexGrid of ComponentOne?

Tags: .net, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am using C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid from ComponentOne. It sorts fine by one column when AllowSorting is set to SingleColumn.

flexGrid.AllowSorting = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.AllowSortingEnum.SingleColumn

But MultiColumn enumeration does not appear to sort at all. I tried to google but did not find any solution that works. Thanks for any help.

flexGrid.AllowSorting = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.AllowSortingEnum.MultiColumn

Comment: What is the version of C1FlexGrid that you are using?

Comment: The product version says 2.6.20073.357. Thank you!

Comment: This could be a bug. Since this is 2007s buld, you can try downloading any other build. You  can see the listing starting with 'dotnet/c1flexgrid' @ http://prerelease.componentone.com/fullindex.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. But I am not sure if I can upgrade our componentone version.

Comment: You must know that you can use your license years' next 3 releases. So you can try changing the builds. There is no other resolution.